# Looping A Dynamic map to load different tables in Informatica BDM

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have created a dynamic mapping in Informatica BDM as follows:

[image]

I created a paramaterized source and target

[image: Source]

[image: Target]

I also created a workflow for the map

[image]

Now what I i am having difficulty with, is changing the source and target parameters at run time to load different tables to different targets using this one dynamic map.

it is like running a map in a loop but each time it runs the source and target parameters changes to read different source and load to different target.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do you can re-import the same mapping into same workflow n times and either you can create workflow parameters and assign those parameters to mapping parameters in input tab in workflow. OR you can create parameter sets and import the mapping parameters inside it, assign the parameter set to mapping in the workflow.
eg.

1. mapping 1 -> parameter set 1
2. mapping 1 -> parameter set 2
   change your parameters value in parameter set and use the same mapping, for more details refer docs (https://docs.informatica.com/data-quality-and-governance/data-quality/10-4-0/developer-workflow-guide/mapping-task/mapping-task-overview/multiple-mapping-tasks-that-run-the-same-mapping.html)